# Adding other data to points in ArcMap document?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I'm a user (not producer) of ArcGIS documents in my work and I need some help asking experts with the following:

I have some Microsoft Word documents and some pictures that describe characteristics of buildings that I have represented in ArcMap 10.1 document as a points in a shape.
I need to have access to the data and pictures when I select any of these points (buildings) clicking on ArcMap project and read this info when needed.

Can I add this both type of data in ArcMap or should I create a separated database and link ArcMap and this DB in any way?

Should I create a PDF file joining MS Word and images to have only one file and access them?

Comment: So you have polygons representing buildings (in Arcmap), and within each of these polygons you have several points with attributes that you are interested in? And you want what..? Add a raster with additional information to this and georeference it to overlap existing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Defining dynamic hyperlinks through Identify results**

> You can dynamically add a hyperlink to a feature using the Identify
>   tool Identify. With dynamic hyperlinks, you do not use an attribute
>   field to supply the hyperlink targets. The hyperlink target you
>   specify is associated with the identified feature. This association is
>   stored with your layer. They are also stored with your layer if you
>   save the layer to a file.
>
> ```
> Click the Identify tool Identify on the Tools toolbar.
> Click the feature for which you want to define a hyperlink.
> Right-click the feature in the Identify window and click Add Hyperlink.
> Specify the desired hyperlink target.
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> The Hyperlink Base setting has no effect on dynamic hyperlinks.
>
> You can specify any number of dynamic hyperlinks for any feature. All
>   the dynamic hyperlinks defined for a feature are listed in the
>   Hyperlinks pull-right list in the identify results context menu (steps
>   1–3 above). Also available from this menu is Manage Hyperlinks. Here,
>   you can add and remove dynamic hyperlinks for this feature. This list
>   does not include field-based hyperlinks, and the commands available
>   have no effect on field-based hyperlinks.

Source:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000